# How to link CSS, javascript and HTML files together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn web dev and did a few courses from codeacademy. It just teaches syntax and meaning of stuff but not how to implement them. Can someone help me to understand how all of the above are linked. I tried making a basic code in which i tried linking some stuff but the css file doesnt link to the HTML file on the webpage.

The code is below

```
<!DOCTYP html>
<HTML>
   <head>

    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body> 
    <div class="nav">
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="pull-left">    
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>TRANSFER STUDENT?</h1>
      <h4>INDIA -> US</h4>
      <a href="#">Learn More</a> 
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <div class="container">
      <p>This website has been hosted specially for Transfer Students from India into the colleges in the United
     States. Information regarding transfers, eligibility, life and other important aspects of college life
     as a transfer student is available. If any more information is required please vist the contacts tab.</p>          
     </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="otherlinks">
     <div class="explorer">
      <h3>Explore and know about College Transfers</h3>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class=""thumbnail">        
     <a href="#"><img src="http://www.dqindia.com/IMG/410/32410/bits01may312k4.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="http://kaw.stb.s-msn.com/i/BC/4C1785CC7D8E3AAB36924732558E36.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="http://m.harvard.edu/modules/home/images/logo-home.png"/></a>
       </div> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

I also made a small css file and tried to make some changes but they are not visible on the page
The css code is below

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    font-size:30px;
    color:blue;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image:url('http://urbanupdate.in/wp-content/uploads/
2014/03/india-us-flag.jpg');
}

.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Also, i am saving these files in the same folder and secondly i am using scoreboard.
Also how to link other files in my computer to the txt file?
I have still not included any jquery code but correct me if i am wrong
The jquery code will go inside two script tags after the script tag where i linked jquery. Right?

Comment: Always do `<link rel="" href="">` because sometimes `<link href="" rel="">` is not working.

Comment: @LeoSarmiento No such thing. The order of HTML attributes do not affect how the CSS file is loaded.

Comment: I don't think this would cause your problem, but your `<!DOCTYP html>` should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Check that your `main.css` file is in the same directory as the `.html` file. To understand how relative and absolute file path works, you can refer to this article: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: Open the network tab in chrome developer tools and refresh the page.  What does it say for the line with the CSS file?  Can you open the css file in your browser by replacing your html file name with `main.css`?  Something's probably not where you think it is, unless there are conflicting CSS rules that may take precedence.  Right-click on the element in chrome and inspect it.  The right side 'styles' tab will show you what rules are applied in the order and strike-out the ones superseded by other rules.

Comment: I corrected the doctype. The files are in the same directory(same folder)

Answer (score 0):

there are many errors in your code but mostly protocol errors:

- line 47 html code syntax error `<div class=""thumbnail">` please replace with `<div class="thumbnail">`
- lines 5, 8, 13 serve the link with `https`
- line 7 (in css), 48, 49, 50 paths for `src` of `<img>` returns 404 not found