# CSS not linking to HTML file

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

Am an actual beginner in the coding world, sorry for the poor slang. I'm going through the html.net tutorial for CSS and though following the same steps as instructed my CSS file is not linking to my HTML file. I've put them both, the HTML File and CSS file, in the same folder called "style" on my hard drive. Am using Chrome Vertion 64.0.3282.186 (Build oficial) (64 bits). Am using TextEdit on OS X Yosemite, am afraid that the issue has to do with that am using a Mac. My brother has been doing the same tutorials in Windows and he has gotten results in some other kind of exercices while I haven't. Here's the link to the tutorial: http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson2.php . Am including some screenshots of my coding [HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlyaW.png) and [CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP6aY.png)

Comment: You should also look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879689/how-to-link-css-javascript-and-html-files-together

Comment: Are you able to check in the post if there's something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you might have done wrong, but the exercise gives the correct instructions. Key points:

- It doesn't matter what the folder is called, only that the two files are side by side in the same folder
- The stylesheet file should be called style.css, as this is what is referred to in the HTML file
- It's the HTML file which links to the stylesheet file, not the other way around
- Watch out for artefacts such as "smart quotes" which aren't the same as quotes (different opening and closing characters which look nice but don't work in a programming context)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Before having posted the question, I applied all of what you kindly have suggested me. I'm including the code to see if you guys can tell me where the error lies.

Comment: So your HTML code is point to `css-folder/style.css` - I'm guessing that's not the folder where your HTML file resides. Take out the path "css-folder/" and try again.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you very much! It's been 2 days of reading and trying out different tutorials to see some results in my page

Comment: Glad to help. Starting out, it's easy to put things in the wrong places and difficult to see how the different parts link together. Hopefully you'll never make the same mistake again! :)